# Create a user-defined function to return a table with customer information?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a user-defined function, but I keep getting this error message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Huckestein_ufnCustomerDemographics, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'RETURNS'.
```

I have been researching this for hours and still can't figure out what is going on... Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Here is my SQL Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Huckestein_ufnCustomerDemographics 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
Select  CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Phone, SalesLT.Address.*
From SalesLT.Customer, SalesLT.Address
```

Comment: Is this SQL Server? Add the tag for the database type

Comment: Yes, I just updated the tags.

Answer (score 2):

Please create that function as shown below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Huckestein_ufnCustomerDemographics()
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN (
SELECT  C.CustomerID, C.FirstName, C.LastName, C.Phone, A.*
FROM SalesLT.Customer C INNER JOIN SalesLT.CustomerAddress AS CA  
        ON C.CustomerID = CA.CustomerID
     INNER JOIN SalesLT.[Address] A
        ON A.AddressID = CA.AddressID

);
GO
```

You can test it as shown below:

```
SELECT * FROM Huckestein_ufnCustomerDemographics()
```

Comment: Seemed like it was going to work.. It said insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the function.

Comment: I tested it on my Azure SQL Database server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE FUNCTION Huckestein_ufnCustomerDemographics 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(Select  CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Phone, SalesLT.Address.*
From SalesLT.Customer, SalesLT.Address);
```

Note the brackets and semi colon. RETURNS TABLE creates an inline table valued function. It is meant to have a single select wrapped in a return statement

Comment: Just really have an explicit JOIN.  This is essentially a CROSS JOIN

Comment: This is the error I got trying the brackets and semicolon:Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

Comment: @JakeHuckestein That usually means the server is having connectivity problems, rather than an issue with the SQL script